# Is pointing to a part of a picture indeed non-trivial research?

Tags: discussion

In [this moderator-deleted answer of mine,](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/36831/22324) I observed that Trump's twitter background picture was cropped from a getty image original just at a line which cut out the copyright watermark. I showed the fact on an edited picture for illustration. The reason given for deletion was "original data analysis or non-verifiable data". The picture was the same as shown in another answer, and is easily verifiable.

I also believe that this is an observation rather than original research, which must be "non-trivial". There is actually no research whatsoever necessary; if one wants to formally label the observation as data analysis at all (all verbal statements about visual perceptions are data analysis, aren't they?), it's trivial. Excluding mere observations from answers would render many answers unsuitable.

What should I do to make the answer acceptable (as far as it goes as an answer)?

<sub>(As an aside, I do see that it is only part of an answer, at best, and would perhaps be more appropriate as a comment, but I cannot post an image in a comment, and it seems to be a relevant detail in the context of the question ("yes, it is a picture from Obama's inauguration, and it may have violated a copyright, too"). This was also not the reason it was deleted.)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't my mod hammer, but I did see it had been deleted by a mod.

I might not have chosen that particular banner, but I was satisfied that it was not an answer, and should have been deleted.

The answer did not provide additional facts that answered the question. Instead it speculated about the motivation of the graphics designers decision, suggesting a a copyright infringement without any evidence - not even a claim by the copyright owner. There is no reason provided not to believe that the full license fees have been paid.

I don't think such unsubstantiated mud-slinging has a place in a Skeptics.SE answer.

Comment: I considered the investigation of copyright infringment, original research.